# Convert CharField to String

Tags: python, pymysql

For a database query with pymysql, I'm getting the model

```
class MyModel(Model):
    id = AutoField()
    date1 = CharField()
    confirmed = IntegerField()
```

Getting the date works, but I have to do some calculations with date1. For this, I need to convert it to a datetime object with datetime.strptime().

```
for model in MyModel.select().where(MyModel.confirmed == 0):
    rd = MyModel.date1
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(rd, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

The problem is that date1 is a CharField, not a string, so strptime does not work. How can I get the content of the CharField into a string? As the rest of the script works the way it is, ideally it would be in a way that doesn't change the retrieved data.

Comment: Use ```str(data1)``` I think it may work

Comment: This simply returns "<CharField: MyModel.date1>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that you're accessing the CharField from the class, rather than an instance of the class. Try this instead:

```
for model in MyModel.select().where(MyModel.confirmed == 0):
    rd = model.date1
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(rd, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: damn, that should have been obvious. I think I need to go back to sleep. Thank you!